# What partition algorithm does this use? (for quicksort)

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I'm working on ["Quick as a Flash" over at CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/239/) and I'm trying to figure out what algorithm they're using for their partition step. [The only hint is the animation they include.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7QWQ.gif)

It looks to be recursive, but I don't know what the logic is. It doesn't seem to the standard "Lomuto" partition scheme as per Wikipedia.

Any pointers would be appreciated, no spoilers on how to complete the challenge, I want to complete it myself; But there simply isn't enough information in the post to continue.

EDIT:

Here's the transition between the states of the list it shows in the animation:

- 5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 4
- 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5
- 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6
- 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

(then repeat)

Comment: [Link to Wikipedia article for the Lumoto approach.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)

Comment: [Link to graphic of an alternate partition scheme from the same article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quicksort-diagram.svg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the animation, they are choosing the first element as the `pivot` every single time, and then swapping the values based on the value of the `pivot`. Values on the left side of the pivot will be less and on right side should be greater. I am not revealing the answer but the below code is just a head start for you!

Below code snippet is for `quicksort` algorithm

```
def partition(A, start, end):
    pivot = A[end]
    pindex = start
    for i in range(start, end):
        if A[i] <= pivot:
            A[i], A[pindex] = A[pindex], A[i]
            pindex += 1

    A[pindex], A[end] = A[end], A[pindex]
    return pindex

def quick_sort(A, start, end):

    if start < end:
        pindex = partition(A, start, end)
        quick_sort(A, start, pindex - 1)
        quick_sort(A, pindex + 1, end)

    return A

print quick_sort([10, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 0, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already implemented and tested the Lumoto approach (as you have here) and it doesn't sort the list as per the animation. I'm assuming that the partition step is key in determining how many pivots are found during the sort, which would change my answer with respect to CodeEvals'? I had a crappy school and so we haven't studied this sort in any way, so I'm not sure if what I'm saying is correct. =/

Comment: I just double checked with CodeEval and the partition algorithm does seem to impact the outcome of some of the tests. The sample data they supply works correctly with the Lumoto approach (as here) and correctly establishes the correct number of pivots. But the other data they use during the testing of an answer differs: my last implementation got ~45/100. I can't examine the errors with the way they format their "results" page, so I have no way of knowing how and why they differ. =/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is just horribly broken:

https://getsatisfaction.com/codeeval/topics/as-quick-as-a-flash
(codeeval's feedback system)

Sorry about not finding that sooner, but apparently the getsatisfaction posting system isn't indexed correctly by Google; As all my previous attempts at finding help on their site or generally through google did not show this result. ><

I'll mark python's answer as correct as it's helpful and really close to what I asked for.

At any rate, the solution appears to be to use the Hoare partition scheme though that's impossible to deduce from the given information in the problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme